# Type.GetType() and Assembly.GetType() returns different results

Tags: c#, .net, types, assemblies

The following code result in different results:

```
class X<R>
{
    public class Y { }
}
```

...

```
var t = typeof(X<int>.Y);
var n = t.ToString().Dump(); // <- X`1+Y[System.Int32]

Type.GetType(n).Dump(); // <-- X`1+Y[System.Int32]
t.Assembly.GetType(n).Dump(); // <-- null
```

Why `Type.GetType(n)` finds the type but `t.Assembly.GetType(n)` not?

Comment: `T Dump<T>(T v)` is from LINQPad, it returns the value and outputs it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, `Assembly.GetType(string)` needs the FULL name of the type.

Try using `FullName` instead of `ToString()` on the type to get the full name, instead of the short name.